# Algebra over the real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We have $A$ that is a finite-dimensional algebra over the real numbers.
And we have $ x \in A $ so that $ 1, x $ and $x^2 $ are linearly independent.

Prove that $ A $ contains two different elements $ a $ and $b$ so that $ab=0$ but $a,b \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

For $n$ large enough, $1,x,x^2,\ldots, x^n$ are linearly dependent, hence there exist non-zero polynomial $f\in\Bbb R[X]$ with $f(x)=0$ in $A$.
Pick such $f$ of minimal degree. Then $\deg f>2$ because $1,x,x^2$ are independent.
As $\deg f>2$, $f$ factors in $\Bbb R[X]$ as $f(X)=g(X)h(X)$ with $\deg g, \deg h\ge 1$. Then $g(x)h(x)=f(x)=0$ but $g(x)\ne 0\ne h(x)$.